# Number of solution for $\sin x = 0$ in $[0,2π]$ are 2 or 3

Tags: trigonometry

Number of solution for a equation $\sin x = 0$ in $[0,2π] $ (close interval) are 2 or 3.  Solutions are of course 0,π,2π but are they three solution or just two solution considering 0 and 2π are same thing for most part? So what is the right answer 2 or 3.According to me answer should be 3 but my book said 2.

Comment: From a numerical point of view, there are  three solutions.

Comment: Three solutions, $0$ and $2\pi$ are different numbers.

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on the logic of '$0$ and $2\pi$ are same thing for most part?' ?

Comment: The right answer is clearly $3$ because the $3$ reals numbers are distinct.

Comment: @HughEntwistle according to me answer should be 3 but my book said it's 2.  So I just assumed that it is because  period of all trigonometric functions are 2π so they don't count.

Comment: Is the interval closed on both sides ? Then, I agree that $3$ is correct.

Comment: @swarnim Perhaps you have misread the domain?

Comment: @HughEntwistle nope may be it's misprint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$0=0.0000000\cdots$ and $2\pi=6.2831853\cdots$, I wouldn't consider that they are "the same thing", even "for most part".

There must be a misunderstanding about what your book says.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed:

$$\sin(0) = 0 $$

$$\sin(\pi) = 0$$

$$\sin(2\pi) = 0$$

Thus there are $3$ solutions.

It doesn't really make sense to argue that $0$ and $2\pi$ are the 'same' because they are different numbers? Yes if we know that $0$ is a solution, then so is $0+2k\pi$ on a suitable domain - but the fact that we exploited periodicity here doesn't make our other solutions more or less different!